# How to override/customize Material theme with Jepack / Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-toolbar, android-compose-textfield, android-compose-layout

1. Material theme restricts setting height on search bar but we want to reduce it because it looks too fatty per our design system
2. Material theme restricts increasing height of the topbar (default height is 56dp) and it also does not go well with our design system

We tried following but to no avail:

1. We tried reducing default height but it shops of the text in search bar
2. Tried increasing height of the top bar but that makes the title in top bar not vertically aligned